# Reduced Chi^2 value interpretations below 1

Tags: chi-squared-test, overfitting, fitting, curve-fitting

I have an experiment where I have fitted an exponential decay over some data taken from a radioactive decay experiment. The fit yields a reduced X^2 of less than 1

[image]

What should be inferred by a X^2 of this type? Does it infer over-fitting? If so, how can I improve the fit (The fit itself isn't perfect since the target is t1/2 = 150s)? And lastly, is a X^2 of 0.693 particularly poor (I'm 90% sure the data this is taken from is a bit crap)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your half-life is statistically consistent with your expectation.

If your model is true, then the number you call $\chi^2$ should follow a $\chi^2$ distribution with the appropriate degrees of freedom. Sometimes the reduced value should be more than one, sometimes less.  Very large values are rare, and tend to be interpreted as a poor fit.  For that, you can calculate the probability of observing such a value or larger, assuming the value comes from a $\chi^2$ distribution with the degrees of freedom you have.

In your case, you are worried your value is too small.  This can also be caused by overestimating the errors on the measurements. Have you checked those?

Lastly, if your model is well-motivated from the standpoint of physics, and the errors are OK, the result seems satisfactory to me.